# How to filter some items in a manytomany field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to make an announcement system in my application whereby the Dean can create an announcement and selects the student he is sending them to. I will like to get a way to be able to filter only the specific student announcement(s) on his/her page.

**Note** : Normally, if I write the code, {{request.user}} in the template, i get "AnonymousUser" which is expected as the normal django User module wasn't implemented but a Custom User model. This shows that request.user.id won't be valid, so it is not an option for me to use to filter.

I hope I can get some other ways to filter each student announcement.

models.py

```
class Announcement_by_dean(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager)
    message = models.TextField()
    sent_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class add_students_by_manager(models.Model):
    manager_ID = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

views.py

```
def student_course_list(request):

    stu_course_id = request.POST.get('stu_course_id')
    my_announcement = Announcement_by_dean.objects.filter(student_id=request.user.id).order_by('-sent_date')
    print(my_announcement)

    context = {"my_announcement":my_announcement}
    return render(request, "student_course_list.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're trying to compare a model instance with an ID of that instance. Changing it to this should do the trick:

```
my_announcement = Announcement_by_dean.objects.filter(student_id__id=request.user.id).order_by('-sent_date')
```

As you can see in the above example though, your naming conventions are a bit confusing. You may want to consider reading up a bit on django coding style: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

If it's not the logged in user (request.user), then you can either pass in the student ID in the URL, as so: [www.yourdomain.com/yourviewurl/?student_id=](http://www.yourdomain.com/yourviewurl/?student_id=)<>
and then change your code to:

```
def student_course_list(request):

    stu_course_id = request.POST.get('stu_course_id')
    my_announcement = Announcement_by_dean.objects.filter(student_id=request.GET['student_id']).order_by('-sent_date')
```

or you can specify a captured value in your urls.py (see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)
And change your code to:

```
def student_course_list(request, student_id):

    stu_course_id = request.POST.get('stu_course_id')
    my_announcement = Announcement_by_dean.objects.filter(student_id=student_id).order_by('-sent_date')
```

Comment: normally, if I write the code, {{request.user}} in the template, i get "AnonymousUser" which is expected as the normal django User module wasn't implemented but a Custom User model.

Comment: I hope I can get a way to filter the announcement pertaining only to the particular student.

Comment: Updated answer above